# Value is not updated immediately in one place however it is updated in the other in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a page that is split into left pane and right pane. The left pane has an option with label "Firmware" which when clicked the right pane displays the corresponding page. The left pane has also a button which when clicked takes us through a series of steps in a wizard. once the wizard is closed the value near the label is updated to the current version but in the right pane there is a conditional rendering based on the same version variable but it is not updated at the first instance. I have to move to a different page and come back to see the changes. I cannot use composition-api since I dont have permission to install that. Is there a way to solve this and also why it is happening. Below is some code for better understanding of the problem.

**right pane -vue file**

```
<q-item-label header v-if="!room.uxOneVersion">
  {{ $t('pages+.projects.firmwares.noVersion') }}
  <span class="lt-md">
    <br />
  </span>
  {{ $t('pages.projects.firmwares.connectThermostat') }}
</q-item-label>
<q-item-label
  class="q-mb-md"
  header
  v-if="room.uxOneVersion && room.uxOneVersion >= versionCheck"
>
  {{ $t('pages.projects.firmwares.noUpgradeAvailable') }}
  <span class="lt-md">
    <br />
  </span>
  {{ $t('pages.projects.firmwares.latestCheck', { date: date, hour: hour }) }}
</q-item-label>
<q-item-label
  class="q-mb-md"
  header
  v-if="room.uxOneVersion && room.uxOneVersion < versionCheck && versionCheck"
>
  {{ $t('pages.projects.firmwares.upgradeAvailable') }}
</q-item-label>
```

**Typescript file for the right pane**

```
async searchUpdate() {
    localStorage.setItem('date', new Date().toLocaleDateString());
    localStorage.setItem(
      'hour',
      new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })
    );
    try {
      this.onSearchFirmware = true;
      if (await Helpers.isHostDeviceOnline()) {
        const firmwareUpdaterResponse = await this.isFirmwareUpToDate(this.firmwareUpdater);
        if (
          firmwareUpdaterResponse &&
          !firmwareUpdaterResponse?.isUpToDate &&
          this.room.uxOneVersion < firmwareUpdaterResponse?.version &&
          this.versionCheck != firmwareUpdaterResponse?.version
        ) {
          localStorage.setItem('version', firmwareUpdaterResponse.version);
          this.versionCheck = localStorage.getItem('version');
          this.notifyAvailabilityOfNewVersionFirmware(firmwareUpdaterResponse);
          this.date = localStorage.getItem('date');
          this.hour = localStorage.getItem('hour');
        } else {
          this.notifyNoVersionFirmwareAvailable();
          this.date = localStorage.getItem('date');
          this.hour = localStorage.getItem('hour');
        }
      } else {
        Notifier.showError(this.$t('general.internetNotConnected').toString());
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const errorMessage = this.$t('pages.projects.firmwares.isUpToDateError', {
        error_message: (error as FirmwareUpdaterError).message,
      }).toString();
      Notifier.showError(errorMessage);
    } finally {
      this.onSearchFirmware = false;
    }
  }
```

**left pane- vue**

```
<q-item-section side>
  <div>
    <q-chip style="background: transparent"></q-chip>
    <q-chip data-cy="firmware-Version" v-if="room.uxOneVersion != ''"
      >{{ $t('general.currentVersionFirmware') }} {{ room.uxOneVersion }}</q-chip
    >
    <q-icon size="xs" color="grey" name="chevron_right" />
  </div>
</q-item-section>
```

**Typescript for left pane**

```
this.handleConnectionDialogVisibility(false);
  await this.getVersionUxOne();
  await this.openIdentifyDialog();
}
private async getVersionUxOne() {
  this.firmwareVersionToDisplay = '';
  const controllerUpdater = ControllerFirmwareUpdaterFactory.create(
    this.roomControllerModuleStore.currentController.controllerType,
    this.deviceModuleStore.currentNetworkAddress,
    this.deviceModuleStore.currentPassword
  );
  const currentControllerVersion = await controllerUpdater.getVersion(); //0.2.9
  const room: RoomEntity = this.roomModuleStore.currentRoom;
  room.uxOneVersion = `${currentControllerVersion}`; //0.2.9
  this.firmwareVersionToDisplay = `v ${currentControllerVersion}`; //v 0.2.9
  await this.roomModuleStore.updateRoom(room);
  await this.roomModuleStore.setCurrentRoom(this.roomModuleStore.currentRoom.Id);
}
```

Comment: ....but in the right pane there is a conditional rendering based on the same version variable but it is not updated... Can you please be more specific: witch is the conditional rendering based on the same version variable. Post the line.  Maybe the problem is not the variable but the "condition" whitch uses the variable. Print the "variable" in left and right panes WITHOUT contitons. If you can see it then look for the logic of the v-if and the values  with which you compare the "variable"

Comment: v-if="room.uxOneVersion && room.uxOneVersion >= versionCheck" this is the condition. when i print room.uxOneVersion in both the left and right pane, the left pane value is updated without any refresh but right pane is not

Comment: The code is a part of what?  Each component must refer to the same object through the store, so they look the same. In your code, the left and right components do not appear to refer to the same object.